# QGIS find and replace several unicode symbols in a single field, including replacing an apostrophe

Tags: qgis-3, expression, replace

I work with languages that use Unicode symbols in their placenames. I often receive layers with labels that display incorrectly, but they are messed up in the same way all the time eg: the place name shows Ñ but it should read K̲, or ñ should be k̲.

I have the code for a single find and replace, but I would like to batch find and replace all the problem letters at once. How do I string together several letter replacements?

This is the code I have to replace a single letter:

```
replace("field",'find_value','replace_value')
```

But I would like it to fix all of these values at once:

```
  replace("Label",'Ñ','K̲')
  replace("Label",'Ý','X̲')
  replace("Label",'Ç','G̲')
  replace("Label",'ç','ɢ̲')
```

---

I also need to replace a regular apostrophe ' (U+0027) in the middle of the word word with a right single quotation mark (U+2019) style apostrophe. This is my code that doesn't work:

```
replace("Label",''','’')
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to fix the imported files encoding so it is not broken?

Comment: I don't know enough about these things to know how the file encoding gets broken. It has  happened to a lot of shapefiles I get. They were all made a decade or so ago, and for whatever the reason, the attribute tables have altered unicode letters. It might be an ESRI to QGIS thing, but I don't have a way to test that.

Comment: It just means that the default encoding is set wrong. Experiment with one of the shapefiles until it works and then set the default

Comment: I have since learned that the files are built to be used with a special font that was made to display/translate the unicode letters for this language (they show properly as labels when I use this particular font). But it is a font that does not display well for cartography (tall and thin with big serifs). So I would prefer to just quickly correct the formatting of the letters in the attribute table so that I can use any unicode font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` variant of `replace`, where the map is a series of key-value, the key being the string being searched for and the value being the replacement string

```
replace("Label",map('Ñ','K̲','Ý','X̲','Ç','G̲','ç','ɢ̲'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a regular apostrophe ' (U+0027) in the middle of the word word with a right single quotation mark (U+2019) style apostrophe using this expression:

```
replace("Label",'\'','’')
```